# i want to connect with Firebase but i have an error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, build.gradle

I want to connect with Firebase but I have an error: "could not parse the android application modules gradle config.resolve gradle build issues and/or resync." and i check my gradle . if i sync gradle i have a warning "WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'."

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "dxd.zzz.axy"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
    // but continue the build even when errors are found:
    abortOnError false
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
implementation 'com.mohamadamin:persianmaterialdatetimepicker:1.2.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.1.0'
implementation files('libs/sqliteassethelper-2.0.1.jar')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: i think you should upgrade to the latest version and also add firebase-core, check my answer below may help you

Comment: This solution works for me: stackoverflow.com/a/49742260/7705712

Comment: also from the firebase docs you should use API 16 or later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write latest version of gms service in app level gradle
Please see the below image

[image]

Comment: latest version is 4.0.1

Comment: Yes i told that you should use latest version...this is old image.

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure you are using latest google services version (Project Level):

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

Then change your code, you should also add firebase-core like below.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dxd.zzz.axy"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    implementation 'com.mohamadamin:persianmaterialdatetimepicker:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation files('libs/sqliteassethelper-2.0.1.jar')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Moreover, if you want to use other firebase libraries right now please keep up to the latest version like below and always take a look in [this link](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) to be sure that you using the latest version.

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about that warning. If it builds successfully then no problem at all.

Comment: but i can't connect with firebase

Comment: Check internet permission and also don't forget to add firebase config file form console to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the latest library for firebase

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
```

And make sure you have to add firebase config file form consol to your project.